# wkhtmltopdf header on every page

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert html to pdf.

I want to add header in every page, but it only shows up in the first page (table of contents).
The command I am using is `"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" toc --xsl-style-sheet default.xsl --header-html header.html http://a-url-to-a-page.com "some\folder\outputs\output-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.pdf"`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you solve it :) wkhtmltopdf is particular about the order of arguments given.

Answer (score 6):

(Solved by the OP and answered by a question edit. Transcribed here as a community wiki answer - although its a bit terse. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Finally solved, the problem was that `--header-html` should come before the table of contents related stuff...

@Nenotlep wrote:

> `wkhtmltopdf` is particular about the order of arguments given.

Answer (score 0):

--header-html Work fine, no issues..

1. file:// not required.
2. complete header tag should be in file

Note: https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/97#issuecomment-137088664